# c# mvc5 server errors fully English while keeping uiculture on auto

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, localization, runtime-error

Im using ResourceFiles for my language specific text in a website. the webconfig is configured in this order:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

My site switches to the language the user's Headers deliver and i want to maintain this automatic behavior, but i want to force my entire server error info (yellow pages) to be always english. right now the exception itself is in english but the surrounding information on the yellow page is presented in the auto language (dutch in my case)

i'm looking for a elegant solution that uses most of MVC ASP.NET build-in features instead of loads of custom code, something like capturing all error events in global.asax and temporarly converting culture so the server errorpage is english, and then switching back.

Any ideas or tips / snippets?

ps: i want to show my users custom errorpage when in production stage, but i'm going to log exceptions and want to allow remote debugging without the custom error page.

i'm not interested in disabling auto-culture and i this is NOT about input validation error languages so please dont mark this question as duplicate to one of those questions

Comment: A simple but silly approach: set culture and uiculture both to auto and set culture env of your server to en-us.

Comment: @Nathan Isn't that still putting the uiCulture to the Client instead of the server? It should work with the Culture setting but i already made it static English so we are actually only looking at the uiCulture and i dont want to force uiCulture to the server's uiCulture since then the ui will always be English. Or am i confusing something and should i re-read about culture and uiculture automation?